# Highcharts value undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having trouble in adding data to the chart. I am declaring the variable right before i add it to the chart and it says "undefined". I am using a column stacked chart.

```
var result = entregaProg * (Math.pow(1 + taxaRend, prazo) - 1) / taxaRend;

            var capital = result.toFixed(0);

            graphicPR.addSeries({
                name:"Seguro Poupança",
                data:[capital]
            },true);
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: already did it and doesn't work.

Comment: might  be variable scope problem , declare variable as globally and then assign it. Declare it at the top of the script

Comment: check if it is giving any divided by 0 exception

Comment: Can you recreate it as live demo ?